# Накладывается один элемент на другой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Слайдеры накладываются на форму.
Код css слайдера:

```
.slider{
  padding-top: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /* thumb and track color */
  scrollbar-width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Код css формы:

```
#form_input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста!
Не понимаю как это работает...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При написании у слайдера float: left; выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этой информации не достаточно, чтобы дать ответ на вашу проблему. Вы можете ее легко решить, нажав ф12

Comment: Вам необходимо показать полностью ваш код. html/css/js что бы было понимание как у вас это создано. Используете ли готовые библиотеки или изобретаете велосипед.